# PHP Fix Relative Image Path Using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a php file, for example `www.example.com/folder/test.php`

The file above (test.php) has the line

`include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$page);`

`$page = /folder2/.$directory1./.$directory2./.index.php`

`$directory1` and `$directory2` are all random.

However,

The index page has an image on it that just references the image as the source.

For Example src="image.bmp"

So what happens is the image's url actually shows up like this...
`www.example.com/folder/image.bmp`

And it should show up like this...
`www.example.com/folder2/.$directory1./.$directory2./image.bmp`

Is there a way to fix this besides using absolute paths?
There are millions of directories and we would like to correct the issue rather than correct the problem (even though we will do both).

Can I place an htaccess file in the directory its looking for the image in to redirect it?

FROM: `www.example.com/folder/`

TO: `www.example.com/folder2/.$directory1./.$directory2./`

Comment: Instead of absolute urls, check out root-relative urls. e.g. `/folder/image.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that, you should either dynamically change the .htaccess or specify in it any possible `$directory1/$directory2` combination. In my opinion, the best way to do this is to change the `src` of that image in the file `index.php` to something like:

```
<img src="/folder2/<?php echo $directory1; ?>/<?php echo $directory2; ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I think my problem might actually be in include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$page); Is there a way to just open this page in another window while still passing variables to it?

Comment: If you want to open it in another page, you should pass variables using the url like http://www.somesite.com/?one=dummy&two=foo.

Comment: I dont want to do that. Is there another way besides include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$page); to include the other page but use the relative paths correctly on that page.

Comment: I'm not understanding, why can't you use those `echo`? I mean, why should the url be relative? Is that page (the included one) openable on its own?

Comment: The first page opens a new window (test.php) containing the include we are talking about above. It shows in the browser with the URL = the test.php directory, and the include is working fine when it includes the path to the actual $page, its just that include is looking for the image in the test.php directory and I need it to look in the $page directory for it.

Comment: This site shows exactly what I am speaking of, but is there a way around it other than using absolute paths? http://www.gamedev.net/topic/412335-php-include--file-path-problems/

Comment: I'm still not getting it. If you have the include in the page `test.php`, then all the variables of that page will be available in the included page, that means that $directory1 and $directory2 will be available in the page `$page`, so why can't you echo those variables in the URL of the image using the code I posted above?

Comment: Because there are millions of those pages. The problem is that when a file is included it is interpreted from the location of the calling script. So if that file contains includes to other files, the path to that file should be either absolute or relative to the path of the calling script. I believe there is no way around it, therfore we will fix the source of the issue and wait for everything to update over time I guess.

Comment: I think I get the problem but without a clear structure of the directories and the includes I don't know how to sort this out. :/ I'm sorry.